# Populate table view with local files

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfilemanager

How can i populate table view with local files. 
What do i need to use. Will it be possible if i use NSFileManager and UITableView in combination ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use NSFileManager's directoryContentAtPath to get the list of all the files and directory at a given path. directoryContentAtPath returns NSArray, use the same to populate the table.